# array within indexed numbers

Tags: php, arrays

I tried to test a new thing and just saw an unusual output I am unable to get what exactly is happening within the loop can anyone explain me what happens if we take an array and assign that array to a variable we run a for loop and we provide $array and index of $array with the inititlizer for forloop something like this $array[$array[$i]] so I mean I am confused to totally explain but can you review the code and let me know what exactly is happening

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55);

$sum = 0;

for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $sum += $array[$array[$i]];
}
echo $sum ;
```

The output 78 as it added the value but if i remove $sum+= and write down like this

```
  echo $array[$array[$i]] . "<br />";
```

so now what here is I will be getting output like this

2
3
5
13
55

I am unable to get what exactly hapend within this loop

Comment: Why is it `$array[$i]`? And why add `"<br />"` to an integer?

Comment: brother was checking by just echoing the value  echo $array[$array[$i]] . "<br />";  by placing question here i forgot to remove

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the value of the array to access the key.

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55);

$sum = 0;

for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $sum += $array[$array[$i]] . "<br />";
}
echo $sum ;
```

Loop 1:

```
$i = 0;
$sum += $array[$array[0]];
$sum += $array[1];
$sum += 2;
```

Loop 2:

```
$i = 1;
$sum += $array[$array[1]];
$sum += $array[2];
$sum += 3;
```

Loop 3:

```
$i = 2;
$sum += $array[$array[2]];
$sum += $array[3];
$sum += 5;
```

Loop 4:

```
$i = 3;
$sum += $array[$array[3]];
$sum += $array[5];
$sum += 13;
```

Loop 5:

```
$i = 4;
$sum += $array[$array[4]];
$sum += $array[8];
$sum += 55;
```

So...

```
$sum = 2 + 3 + 5 + 13 + 55 = 80
```

Comment: Okay I got it now it will add the value for the index numbers got it now thank you

Answer (score 1):

For `$i = 0`

- what is `$array[$i]` -> `$array[0]` -> `1`.
- what is `$array[$array[$i]]` -> `$array[1]` -> `2`.

And so on.

Answer (score 1):

**First iteration ($i = 0)**

```
$array[$i] = $array[0] = 1
```

and

```
$array[1] = 2
```

**Second iteration ($i = 1)**

```
$array[$i] = $array[1] = 2
```

and

```
 $array[2] = 3
```

**Third iteration ($i = 2)**

```
$array[$i] = $array[2] = 3
```

and

```
$array[3] = 5
```

**Fourth iteration ($i = 3)**

```
$array[$i] = $array[3] = 5
```

and

```
$array[5] = 13
```

**Fifth iteration ($i = 4)**

```
$array[$i] = $array[4] = 8
```

and

```
$array[8] = 55
```

Answer (score 1):

When $i = 0 $array[$array[$i]] becomes $array[$array[0]] which is $array[1] since $array[0] = 1. So $array[1] evaluates to 2.

Keep thinking the same way.

For example, for $i = 4 $array[$array[$i]] becomes $array[$array[4]] which is $array[8] since $array[4] = 8. So $array[8] evaluates to 55.

Think step by step.

Comment: okay got it was really confused about this thing let me have a look step by step